# Bootsplash kernel

Tags: c, image, operating-system, kernel

My question is simple, I am designing a kernel from scratch, and I was wondering how it is possible to display an image, like linux or windows when the OS boots.

And I mean JUST an image, not an animation. (I am aware that an animation is a series of images)

I switched to VGA mode, and I am writing everything in C. The kernel boots with grub.
Thanks.

Comment: That's been done, sometimes for a logo.  Generally -- obtain a mapping to frame-buffer display area, and copy image data to the mapping; possibly making use of a graphic-library to interpret an image file format.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out.
Can you recommend any graphic library?

Comment: I'd guess a lib might be found searching with google, based on a chosen image-format. If a static image works, might be simpler to store image data as an array[] along with integers for height and width.

Comment: Thank you, I will try